# Vertx MQTT Client unable to handle CONNECTION_REFUSED_TOPIC_NAME_INVALID exception

Tags: mqtt, vert.x

Mqtt Client is throwing below NPE in the stacktrace when server sends a CONNECTION_REFUSED_TOPIC_NAME_INVALID

[2023-04-12 08:26:07,654][vert.x-eventloop-thread-1][ERROR] ?.(:)-Connection refused by the server - code: CONNECTION_REFUSED_TOPIC_NAME_INVALID
[2023-04-12 08:26:07,655][vert.x-eventloop-thread-1][ERROR] ?.(:)-Unhandled exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at io.vertx.mqtt.impl.MqttClientImpl.handleConnack(MqttClientImpl.java:1267) ~[vertx-mqtt-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
at io.vertx.mqtt.impl.MqttClientImpl.handleMessage(MqttClientImpl.java:936) ~[vertx-mqtt-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5

I get above exception when I tried this - >

Client :

```
mqttClient.connect(port,host, connect -> {
                if (connect.succeeded()) {
                    log.warn("connected code: {} ", connect.result().code());
                    mqttClient.subscribe(getTopicMap(), subscribeSentHandler -> {
                        if (subscribeSentHandler.failed()) {
                            log.error(" Failed to send subscription request due to ", subscribeSentHandler.cause());
                          
                        } else {
                            log.info("Successfully sent subscription request with packet ID: {} "
                                    , subscribeSentHandler.result());
                            
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    log.error("Failed to connect to mqtt server: {}", connect.cause().getMessage());
                    
                }
            });
```

Server:

```
endpoint.subscribeHandler(subscribe -> {
                 if(validTopic()){
                                endpoint.subscribeAcknowledge(subscribe.messageId(), grantedQosLevels);
                        } else {
                            endpoint.reject(MqttConnectReturnCode.CONNECTION_REFUSED_TOPIC_NAME_INVALID);
                        }
                        
        });
```

isValidTopic() is custom logic in server which I am checking if topics that client is sending is in the list that is expected by server.

I am expecting that this NPE should be reported back to subscribeSendHandler above in MQTT Client, but seems like it is caught only by vertx.exceptionHandler. Is there any way I can catch this NPE before globally catching it in exceptionHandler ?

Comment: Sound like a bug, can you please file an issue?